# vibration "amplifier" structure to place an accelerometer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

I want to catch very small vibrations with an accelerometer.
Is there any structure that can amplify the vibrations, such as springs or something to place the accelerometer on?

The accelerometer will be placed inside a car.

Comment: what vibrations? ie from which component? if you want body vibrations then attached to the bodywork, if from the suspension system then sprung or unsprung?

Comment: Any structures you use will likely introduce their own harmonics. Depending on what you are measuring, they can alter the measurements significantly enough that the measurements are only valid for your instrumented article. You may find that catching small vibrations is easier with smaller accelerometers, or using strain gages on select structural members.

Comment: @Abel - larger accelerometers are more sensitive.

Comment: Larger accelerometers also alter the frequency response a lot more. Observer effects must be considered.